# Differently scaled axes, but same physical size

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, axis

I have the following PSTricks code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1bp}
  \begin{pspicture}(-176,-176)(176,176)
    % Axes
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psaxes[Dx=32,Dy=32,labels=all,ticks=all,ticksize=-4pt 4pt,Ox=-128,Oy=-128]{-}(-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
    \uput{0pt}[0](0,-160){{\large\itshape{a}}}
    \uput{0pt}[0](-160,0){{\large\itshape{b}}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I want to change the units of the y axis to range between 0 and 100 instead, but also remain the same physical size and location as currently. How do I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,preview,margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \psset{linecolor=black,linewidth=1pt,arrowsize=8pt,unit=1bp}
    \begin{pspicture}(-176,-176)(176,176)
    % Axes
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}
    \psaxes[Dx=25,dx=64,Dy=32,Oy=-128](-128,-128)(-128,-128)(128,128)
    \uput{0pt}[0](0,-160){{\large\itshape{a}}}
    \uput{0pt}[0](-160,0){{\large\itshape{b}}}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code on line 8. Also, after fixing the typo I get 0..100 for both axes instead of just the y axis. I want the x axis to remain in the -128..128 range.

Comment: Then do not change the Dy and delete dy. See edited answer